# Image Zoom Library for ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, zooming

In my ASP.Net application, i have a div which contains around 16 images. I need to implement a 'Zoom' functionality which will zoom the Div on click of a button...

I looked at different Jquery Libraries like Zoomooz, gZoomer etc ..

Most of them use a small and a large image for zooming. I would like to have something like Windows Magnifier type of zoom or screen zoom where the whole div gets zoomed instead of individual images.

Can you suggest me some alternative which are available (Paid Libraries will also do)..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this through jQuery, by using http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/

Here's a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/KwvjL/).

Comment: @Mako, when you get a chance, let me know if it did the trick.

Comment: I gave it a shot but like other jquery zoom libraries, this one also uses a small and a large image. I need something similar to windows magnifier functionality, which can magnify the whole div area instead of individual images

Comment: Have you seen this: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/text.php ? It actually magnifies text, not an image.

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know